# Is there any api for getting video thumbnil and title for metacafe and other video like facebook functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need the api to get the video details like video title and video thubnils.

I just want to know how facebook getting the video details of a video url.

I googled youtube only giving api. Any other way to get this all video thumbnils and titles using video urls.

Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks,

Ramanavel Selvaraju.

Answer (score 1):

This is not ruby-on-rails specific. However, I guess that you could retrieve the HTML page with data, parse it and extract the appropriate data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Is facebook doing in that way ?